# How to change div class when child node in Firebase Database is updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

my goal is to show content in a div element and then display exactly what writing in Firebase Database in accordance with two scenarios: accepted or Rejected. So, it is not working for some reason even when User is logged.

How can it be fixed?

Below is situation.

For console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of null
```

[index.esm.js:695 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'names' of null(anonymous function) @ (index):330(anonymous function) @ index.esm.js:4458mt @ index.esm.js:684t.raise @ index.esm.js:9720t.raiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate_ @ index.esm.js:9674t.raiseEventsForChangedPath @ index.esm.js:9658(anonymous function) @ index.esm.js:12676(anonymous function) @ index.esm.js:11791n.onDataMessage_ @ index.esm.js:12046t.onDataMessage_ @ index.esm.js:11331t.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ @ index.esm.js:11325(anonymous function) @ index.esm.js:11226t.appendFrame_ @ index.esm.js:10831t.handleIncomingFrame @ index.esm.js:10881mySock.onmessage @ index.esm.js:10778](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgctH.png)

For accepted:

```
<div id="one" class="hide">
   <div id="stageone"></div>
</div>
```

For Rejected:

```
<div id="two" class="hide">
  <div id="stagetwo"></div>
  <div id="status"></div>
</div>
```

For database.rules.json

```
{"rules": {".read": true, ".write": true }}
```

For Javascript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var okay = firebase.database().ref("users/" + uid + "/accepted");
    okay.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      $("#stageone").val(data.results);
      $("#one").removeClass('hide');
    });
    var nokay = firebase.database().ref("users/" + uid + "/rejected");
    nokay.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      $("#stagetwo").val(data.names);
      $("#status").val(data.results);
      $("#two").removeClass('hide');
    });
  </script>
```

For Database Structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your database structure pls?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I added DB structure

Comment: Please include database structures as text please. [Images are Evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and make us retype all of that when providing an answer.